# Send email using Cloud Functions and Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

How can I send an email to a person using Cloud Functions and Nodemailer?
On my app there's a contact screen where users can ask questions and send feedback to the app, and when the user presses a button, the Cloud Function gets triggered. However, I don't seem to recieve any emails whatsoever, I even checked the "Spam" folder.
What am I doing wrong?

My code for the Cloud Function looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'exampleemail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'exampleemailpassword'
  }
});

exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const { sender, phone, message } = request.query;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: sender.toLowerCase(),
    to: 'exampleemail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'New feedback email',
    text: `${message} Phone: ${phone}`
  };

  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      response.send(err.toString());
    }
    response.send('Email sent');
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe because the email on the mailOptions `from` is different from the transporter `auth` config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, I had to return a code to the HttpRequest in order to run the function property. Then, it works

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    const { sender, phone, message } = request.query;

    const mailOptions = {
      from: sender.toLowerCase(),
      to: 'exampleemail@gmail.com',
      subject: 'New feedback email',
      text: `${message} \nEmail: ${sender.toLowerCase()}\nPhone: ${phone}`
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return response.status(500).send({
          data: {
            status: 500,
            message: error.toString()
          }
        });
      }

      return response.status(200).send({
        data: {
          status: 200,
          message: 'sent'
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are doing wrong, you can't use gmail's SMTP transport service in server environments other than your own computer

> Gmail has a limit of 500 recipients a day (a message with one To and
> one Cc address counts as two messages since it has two recipients) for
> @gmail.com addresses and 2000 for Google Apps customers, larger SMTP
> providers usually offer about 200-300 recipients a day for free.

So I would recommend you to use a service like [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/) to send emails